# How to disable "S" keyboard indicator light for alternate keyboard layout in Kubuntu 23.04?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, keyboard-layout, indicator

I have English (US) as my primary keyboard layout, and Hebrew as my secondary keyboard layout.
When I switch to Hebrew, using the keyboard shortcut of `Win + Space`, the "S" indicator light on my physical keyboard lights up. When I switch back to English, the light goes out.

On my Razer keyboard, which is a full keyboard with numbers pad, this "S" indicator light is above the four arrow keys. There are five indicator lights there, and "S" is the middle light.

I don't want this "S" indicator to light up when I switch to Hebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `/etc/default/keyboard` file for editing. It probably includes this line:

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp_led:scroll"
```

Change it to:

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

and hopefully you'll notice a difference after next reboot.

Comment: I changed that line to XKBOPTIONS="" but it did not change the behavior, even after a reboot.

Comment: @shmu: In that case it has probably been picked up by the KDE specific config files in `$HOME`. I'm not a Kubuntu user, so all I can recommend is that you should look there.